# Parallel console I/O is Java where one thread is only doing output and one thread is only doing input

Tags: java, multithreading, io, java-io

Recently, I am trying to implement a console based chat-app like feature where I need to be able to take input where there is simultaneous output. A sample demonstration program follows:

```
public static class ParIn implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String ln = "";
            try {
                ln = in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.printf("Your input is (%s)\n", ln);
        }
    }
}

public static class ParOut implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            System.err.println("Hello this is sample");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    executorService.submit(new ParIn());
    executorService.submit(new ParOut());
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

The primary problem with this solution is when there is a System.out it flushes out all the already typed data. Example of that is:

[image: Sample console]

What might be an ideal solution to the problem? Specially, keeping in mind I can't stop the parallel output, so having synchronization across this two threads doesn't seem like a solution to me.

*Already tried ideas:*

A primary idea to solve this problem was to have something equivalent to C's getchar() and that sacrifices the ability to go backspace and reflect that in console, however, that coupled with `\r` can be used to output and continue with the input.

Comment: Easiest is to forget console and switch to a GUI. Otherwise you'll be forced to use a library such as JCurses for more advanced console functionality.

Comment: I was thinking the same after 3-4 hrs of digging. But I thought, in wildest dreams, there might be some solution with the current Console?

Comment: Java wasn't really designed for the console, so the default functionality you get (which needs to be platform independent) is not much. Then again, it doesn't really require a lot to put up a small GUI so it shouldn't be a deal breaker.

Comment: Thank you so much. But without the console, what's gonna make my app look cool! (last line was a joke)